# How do I use IOptions in WPF CORE 5?

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration, appsettings

I have a worker service app that uses different appsettings files per deployment i.e. Dev, Test, Prod. The template starts with the Program `static void main` as usual and then goes on to IHostBuilder as usual...

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        IConfiguration config = hostContext.Configuration;
        // more stuff using config including...
        services.Configure<KepwareSettings>(config.GetSection("KepwareSettings"));
    }
 }
```

This is working just fine. Note that IOptions is supported with `services.Configure<class>(config.GetSection("mysection"))`
I'm also using appsettings per environment in a WPF app that uses code from Tim Corey:

```
public App()
{
    ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(services);
    _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
}

private IConfiguration GetConfiguration()
{
    IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

    builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT")}.json");

    return builder.Build();
}

private void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
{
    IConfiguration config = GetConfiguration();
    string conn = config.GetConnectionString("Neenah_SFC_ConnectionString");

    services.AddSingleton(config);

    // more stuff with config but with ERROR on this line
    services.Configure<TestSettings>(config.GetSection("TestSettings"));
}
```

The services.Configure isn't working. The error I get is `cannot convert from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection to System.Action<MyApp.TestSettings>` I've been comparing all the Nuget packages and all the usings at the top. I made sure that Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection and .Configuration are the same in Nuget. When I look at the declarations from metadata for IServicesCollection.Configure they're different.

```
public static IServiceCollection Configure<[DynamicallyAccessedMembers((DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes)(-1))] TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config) where TOptions : class;

public static IServiceCollection Configure<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<TOptions> configureOptions) where TOptions : class;
```

The first one is from the worker service app that works. The second one comes from the WPF app that doesn't work. The metadata for the first one says `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions` which is not in any Nuget packages I have set up..

[image: Worker App Nuget Packages]

I tried adding the Nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` and added the using statement, no luck there. I've spent hours searching and found examples of console apps, web app .NET API, per deployment settings in MVC, and WPF. But I can't find the IOptions pattern with `services.Configure<MySettings>(config.GetSection("MySettings"))` in a WPF app that I get from NET CORE 5 WPF template. What's the right way to do this?

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this package: Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions